# Earphones stuck in call answer mode

Tags: earphone

So I've got this problem with my earphones where they're stuck in call answer mode. They have a button which when pressed should switch the music to the background when in call answer mode and back to normal when pressed again. Well now I have the problem where the only way to have them back to normal mode is to press and hold the button. I have no idea myself how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I require small information.

What mobile do you use ?

You're saying your phone is stuck in call answer mode. That means even though you disconnect your earphones from your mobile and you play the songs, the music can't be heard unless you switch it to a speaker. Is that it ?

Comment: No you've gotten it wrong. The phone's audio is fine, the problem is in the earphones. The earphones have a button on them that you press when you want to answer a call so it switches all audio and music to the background. It's stuck in that mode and I need it back to normal.